# Restoring data from Time Machine backup created on second Mac

Tags: time-machine, restore

I have a desktop Mac and MacBook Air.

The MacBook Air has decided to die, so I want to restore the back up files in my Time Machine to my Mac desktop.

How do I do that?

It must be simple, but I can only get into the data for my Mac desktop.

Answer (score 2):

⌥ alt/option-click the Time Machine icon in the menu bar and keep the key held whilst selecting Browse Other Backup Disks….

[image]

From there, you can select the other Mac and copy files.

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply but i only see select disk... no browse other backup disks...

Comment: @Barbara Are you selecting it from the menu bar? I've added a screenshot

Comment: my menu bar under the latest backup and date says...Back-up now... Enter Time Machine...open ™ preferences

Comment: @BarbaraFranken are you clicking on the small circle with clock

Comment: @Buscar Yes, those are the correct options

Comment: @Barbara You need to hold alt (⌥) whilst clicking the option, and keep it held whilst you select the option.

Comment: ok got that now thanks but still showing only one disk which is my mac... do you think they are all mixed up in this one disk?  sorry but i'm quite a dummy...