# How to restore backups manually from Time Machine?

Tags: time-machine, restore

I bought a new Mac a few days ago. I did a clean install, so I can start blank. Now I want to restore some files back from Time Machine to the new Mac. Is there a way to get the Time Machine interface so I can travel through my old backups using TM on my new Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To restore the latest backup, connect the drive used for Time Machine to the new Mac and run `/Applications/Utilities/Migration Assistant.app`. There is also a [support document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204350) from Apple covering this (but it reads some reading between the lines because it covers several use cases as once).

To access the backup as a whole, see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/132623/9058).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried the last option to get access to the whole backup. I access the TM interface after holding alt + click. I will see all dates at the right side, but there is now way to click on a date or travel back in time. What does I do wrong?

Comment: I can't verify this here. @grgarside, any idea?

Comment: I can only travel through "Programs", the tab "Documents" etc I can't access..

Comment: I just got the method to get access to my previous backups. My Mac User name is different from my last one, so he can't find older backups from my new mac name, that's right. So I retrieve the level inside finder so I see the user and from there I can access my older backups. Thanks for the time and answers!